# How to set stackoverflow page to local time zone

Tags: stack-overflow, stackexchange

Since I have became a user on stack-overflow, I'm having issues with the time stamps on questions and comments. The time stamp is not taking my local time zone. I have looked around in the profile settings and searched for a solution but no luck.
Any idea ?

Comment: Hello, questions about StackOverflow should be asked on [Meta StackOverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on Meta.StackOverflow

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Email:

> Hello,
>
> We do not ever display the time in a local time zone. Every timestamp
>   on our site always uses UTC time.
>
> Regards, Stack Overflow Team